# Angular. How to change model value during validation in input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please, tell me how to describe a directive 'myValidation' for input-field

```
<input my-validation ng-model="myValue">
```

to make it behave as follows:

1. if user inputs `'A'` directive must change `myValue` to `'B'` (showing it in input field)
2. otherwise just remain original value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a watch on `myValue` and perform your validation when the value is changed...

```
angular.module('App', [])
    .directive('myValidation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal === 'A') {
                    scope.myValue = 'B';
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMTVm/1/

Comment: Thank you, Anthony. If you can, please answer how to prevent chain reaction in $watch. I understand why it happens, but can't figure out the way to change its behaviour. Let's extend body of $watch 2nd argument in your example to see what I mean. If we claim
        
        if ( newVal === 'A' ) {
          scope.myValue = 'B'
        }
        else if ( newVal === 'B' ) {
          scope.myValue = 'C'
        }
then on input

Comment: ... then on input 'A' we obtain 'C' in input-field, but I want it to be 'B'. I understand why it happens, but can't figure out the way to change its behaviour.

Comment: Interesting question... You do have access to the old value so in theory you can inspect it and not transition to `'C'` if `newValue === 'B' && oldValue === 'A'`. But that doesn't exactly scream elegance and it might not work if it gets any more complicated.

Comment: And if model is complex: ng-model="item.myValue" - how to access to model from scope in general case (without hardcoding names)?

Comment: Good point! I don't like the tight coupling to the scope either... Updated example to watch the ngModel rather than myValue directly.